# Why cache is not clear in ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, caching

I have external js file that run home.php file by using ajax request.

Everything is fine in my code. But the cache is not clear even I add random function in url.

Here is my js code.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }    
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://myurl/home.php?t="+Math.random(),true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader( "Pragma", "no-cache" );
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader( "Cache-Control", "no-cache" );
xmlhttp.send();
```

Every time I call this js file from index.php, I get cache result.

To avoid cache problem, I already add unique id in url. But it doesn't work. So, please give me any suggestion to solve this problem.

Comment: It can't be browser cache, if it `unique url` then browser douse not have cached information about it, you can test it with `Firefox` or chrome `incognito` mode. I guess you have some caching at php side try to debug your php script

Comment: If I change something in that js file such as adding alert message, and call again from index page, it cannot change directly. So, I clear cache from history and run again, I get the correct result. why?

Comment: You are talking about `ajax` request url cache ? or `js` include url cache on the page  `<script src="url/some.js"></script>` ? that 2 are different things

Comment: I mean js include url cache. I call my js file from index.php like this `<script src="url/test.js"></script>`. How different these two thing?

Comment: From your question i understood that you where adding `Math.random()` param to `ajax` url here `xmlhttp.open("GET","http://myurl/home.php?t="+Math.random(),true);` it not working and my first answer was related to that, and yes it is different thing then include js file in your html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid `js` or `css` files include caching issue ( answer to your question in question comments ), you have to change their include links automatically after each change, for this you can use `filemtime("file")`in recourse include step in `html`

`filemtime` return you file creation time, look for manual here about - http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

```
<script 
   src="http://url/some.js?t=<?php filemtime("PATH_TO_FILE/some.js") ?>" >
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
   href="http://url/some.css?t=<?php filemtime("PATH_TO_FILE/some.css") ?>" >
```

So by this way during each modification of `some.js` or `some.css` their creation time will change and to your `home.php` will be added new url links (`http://url/some.js?t=14....`) to that recourse and bowser will have to load them again